# AWS Cost explorer: what entity is actually causing the costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I looked in the daily view of the AWS cost explorer and i see that i am causing costs every day. I have no monthly cost report yet, so how am i able, what is actually causing my costs?

I would like to see, what service or what resource is causing my costs for example which EC2 instance or which S3 bucket.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i click on usage type, i can how the costs are distributed.